# How to map Command key to Control key when using iTerm

Tags: macos, iterm2, keymap

I already mapped "Caps Lock" key to "Command" key using System Prefrences of macOS, as I use "Command" key frequently when using most application.

When using iTerm2, I use "Control" key at most time. Is it possible to map "Command" key (actually the "Caps Lock" key in keyboard) to "Control" when using iTerm2?

Update:
**From iTerm2 Preferences > Keys > Remap Modifiers, remap Control to

Left Command, Left Command and Right Command to Control worked for me**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the very same problem. Only thing I found out is that in iTerm2 you can change the modifier keys. Unfortunately, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is not among the ones that you can change.

So an alternative is to map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Command</kbd> in the system settings and then in iTerm2 map <kbd>Left Command</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd>. Unfortunately, that changes both the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> AND the <kbd>Command</kbd> key. So it's not perfect.